# Doctrine 2 Sementical Error couldn't find constant utilisateursadresses

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

I get this error **[Semantical Error] Couldn't find constant utilisateursadresses, class Ecommerce\EcommerceBundle\Entity\Uti   lisateursAdresses** whene i try php app/console doctrine:generate:entities EcommerceBundle:UtilisateursAdresses

my code :

```
namespace Ecommerce\EcommerceBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * UtilisateursAdresses
 *
 * @ORM\Table(utilisateursadresses)
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Ecommerce\EcommerceBundle\Repository\UtilisateursAdressesRepository")
 */
class UtilisateursAdresses
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Entity\Utilisateurs",inversedBy="adresses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $utilisateurs;
```

and my user code :

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class Utilisateurs extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic

        $this->commandes=new \Doctines\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->adresses=new \Doctines\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Ecommerce\RcommerceBundle\Entity\Commandes",mappedBy="utilisateurs",cascade={"remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $commandes;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Ecommerce\RcommerceBundle\Entity\UtilisateursAdresses",mappedBy="utilisateurs",cascade={"remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $adresses;

    /**
     * Add commandes
     *
     * @param \Ecommerce\RcommerceBundle\Entity\Commandes $commandes
     * @return Utilisateurs
     */
    public function addCommande(\Ecommerce\RcommerceBundle\Entity\Commandes $commandes)
    {
        $this->commandes[] = $commandes;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove commandes
     *
     * @param \Ecommerce\RcommerceBundle\Entity\Commandes $commandes
     */
    public function removeCommande(\Ecommerce\RcommerceBundle\Entity\Commandes $commandes)
    {
        $this->commandes->removeElement($commandes);
    }

    /**
     * Get commandes
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getCommandes()
    {
        return $this->commandes;
    }

    /**
     * Add adresses
     *
     * @param \Ecommerce\RcommerceBundle\Entity\UtilisateursAdresses $adresses
     * @return Utilisateurs
     */
    public function addAdress(\Ecommerce\RcommerceBundle\Entity\UtilisateursAdresses $adresses)
    {
        $this->adresses[] = $adresses;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove adresses
     *
     * @param \Ecommerce\RcommerceBundle\Entity\UtilisateursAdresses $adresses
     */
    public function removeAdress(\Ecommerce\RcommerceBundle\Entity\UtilisateursAdresses $adresses)
    {
        $this->adresses->removeElement($adresses);
    }

    /**
     * Get adresses
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getAdresses()
    {
        return $this->adresses;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
@ORM\Table(utilisateursadresses)
```

to this:

```
@ORM\Table(name="utilisateursadresses")
```